# Google Cast & Android

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm attempting to get familiar with Google Cast and it's usage inside an Android application. The codebase I am working with has a working integration, but seems to have various discrepancies when compared to the [official guides](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate).

For example, one of the first steps in the guide is to implement the `OptionsProvider` interface, like so:

```
class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {
        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
            .build();
        return castOptions;
    }
    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, the codebase i'm working with does not implement this interface anywhere in the application. Confused, I took a look at the dependencies and noticed the following dependency:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:$androidGoogleServicesVersion'`

This was odd, as the guide recommends using the following instead:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1'`

Googling the differences between the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework` library and the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast` library returned no usable results.

Additionally, I was unable to find these libraries on either [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) or [maven](https://mvnrepository.com).

My questions:

1. What are the differences between `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast`?
2. Where are these libraries hosted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So there is a lot to unpack here...

**1.**
It sounds like your app is using CCL, which is a modified version of the v2 client.  You can verify this by searching your app's build.gradle for the "com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl" dependency.  This requires com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast rather than com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework, although play-services-cast is a transitive dependency of play-services-cast-framework, so it will be included implicitly.  CastOptionsProvider is a new thing for the v3 cast api. ($androidGoogleServicesVersion is a groovy variable that is providing the version number and should be set somewhere else, like in your projects top level build file.  This represents the 10.0.1.)

**CCL**
https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

**CCL -> v3 Migration**
https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ccl_migrate_sender

**2.**
These libraries are either pulled from your local SDK.  In the SDK tool it is under SDK Tools/Google Play services.  Now it can be pulled from Google's maven repo, which can be setup via the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven.  As a note, in AndroidStudio 3.0 you can simply use google() to load it.